# How do cameras work?

Tags: payday-2

On Day three of Framing Frame (but also in other missions, such as the mission where you enter the FBI building) there are cameras available which you access by interacting with a laptop on the roof. This connects to all of the cameras installed in the paintings (in this instance) that you stole on day one;

[image]

I have a few questions about how the cameras mechanic works in Payday 2;

- Using the cameras mark the guards for the rest of my crew, do I need to continue using the cameras in order for the guards to remain marked?
- Does it matter which camera I'm currently viewing or are all guards near any of the cameras marked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using the cameras mark the guards for the rest of my crew, do I need to continue using the cameras in order for the guards to remain marked?

Yes. Guards stay marked only for a certain amount of time, then the mark disappears. You'll have to mark them again (either personal with the F key, or via looking at them through a camera).

> Does it matter which camera I'm currently viewing or are all guards near any of the cameras marked?

The camera matters, but not the time used looking at them. What that means - you can switch cameras rapidly and all guards, visible through the camera, will be marked.